# Netsuite Opportunity Field

Tags: transactions, field, workflow, netsuite

We have a workflow in place that is sending a follow up to the email on the customer record instead of the email for communications on the opportunity record. I have tried to implement a workaround for adding a new email field to source it's data directly from the "to be emailed" field. However, the field it a checkbox field and i can't access the text box field to the right of it.

The problem is that it is sending quote follow ups to an email address that may not actually need to receive the quote or may even not know about the quote.

The problem would be obsolete if i could pull data from that text box to the right of "To be emailed" but it only is recognized as a "checkbox" field. even though there is a text field next to the checkbox. Since the field is native to netsuite i cannot seem to find it to modify it for my needs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a simple client script that will trigger when the checkbox is checked and get the value in the textbox to the right.

It will then store the value in a hidden custom field.  This custom field will then be used by the workflow for the email address for sending the email.

Comment: I can't seem to find a field that references that text box field though. I would like to avoid trying to write a script for this.

Comment: I have, Occasionally when we create sales orders or quotes we the email on the sales order or quote differentiates from the email on the customer record. We actually currently use the "email" field id.

Comment: The Issue is that the field "to be emailed" is a check box type. i cannot seem to find what field is housing the email entered on the sales order

Comment: The text field next to the 'To be emailed" checkbox should have the field id "email".

Comment: the field id "email" derives from the customer record and doesn't send from the field that has the email typed in it. it seems like a ghost field

Comment: Do you have any records with the textbox populated.  You can get the field id by adding &xml=T at the end of the URL and search for the email address entered.

Comment: yes we have quite a few records with the field populated, how where do i ad "&xml=T". i want to be able to reference that particular email in a ten day delay in a workflow, but it uses the customer record email id

Comment: The address bar of your browser, add &xml=T at the end of the URL. Then search for the email address, it should give you the field where NetSuite stores it.